# How to pass first row column value some columns in second row sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to pass some columns value in the second row in SQL here is my full query if anyone can help me to solve.

```
SELECT 
   tblCustomers.CustName,
   tblPurchase.PurchaseID,
   ISNULL(tblPurchase.PurInvoiceNo, 0) AS InvoiceNo,
   tblPurchase.PurShowName,
   tblPurchase.PurNotes,
   tblPurchase.PurDepartment,
   tblPurchase.PurQuoteId,
   ISNULL(tblQuote.DeliveryDate,'') AS DeliveryDate,
   tblBranch.BranchCode,
   tblBranch.BranchID,
   tblPurchaseStatus.PurStatusDesc,
   tblPurchase.PurEntered AS IssuedDate,
   tblPurchase.PurEntered,
   tblEmployee.EmployeeName AS IssuedBy,
   tblQuote.SalesRep,
   tblQuote.ProjectLead,
   tblPurchase.PO_Code,
   tblPurchase.PurVendorID,
   tblCustomers.CustType,
   tblPurchase.PurDeliveryDate,
   tblPurchase.PurReturnDate,
   ISNULL(tblEmployee_1.EmployeeName, '') AS ApprovedBy,
   tblPurchase.PurReferenceNo,
   tblPurchase.PurTax,
   tblPurchase.PurTaxRate,
   tblPurchase.PurTaxExempt,
   tblPurchase.CustID,
   tblPurchase.PurSubTotal,
   ISNULL(tblPurchase.PurQuoteIncome,'') PurQuoteIncome, 
   ISNULL(tblPurchase.PurQuoteLaborIncome,'') PurQuoteLaborIncome,
   tblPurchase.PurLabor,
   tblPurchase.PurPoLoss,
    '01/01/1900' AS QID,
   tblPurchase.PurEquipment,
   tblQuote.QuoteTotal - tblQuote.QuoteTaxAmount AS Total,
   tblQuote.QuoteRentalID
    ,[dbo].[SummarySAR]([tblPurchase].[PurchaseID],[tblPurchaseCodes].[PurCode],'R') [EquipmentRental]
    ,[dbo].[SummarySAR]([tblPurchase].[PurchaseID],[tblPurchaseCodes].[PurCode],'L') [Labor]
    ,[dbo].[SummarySAR]([tblPurchase].[PurchaseID],[tblPurchaseCodes].[PurCode],'S') [Shipping]
    ,[dbo].[SummarySAR]([tblPurchase].[PurchaseID],[tblPurchaseCodes].[PurCode],'P') [EquipmentPurchase]
    ,[dbo].[SummarySAR]([tblPurchase].[PurchaseID],[tblPurchaseCodes].[PurCode],'O') [Others]
    ,SUM([tblPurchaseSub].[PurSubDiscTotal]) [SumOfPurSubDiscTotal]
    ,[tblPurchaseSub].[PurSubTaxable] 
    ,([tblPurchase].[PurTaxRate]  * SUM([tblPurchaseSub].[PurSubDiscTotal]) ) / 100 [TaxTotal]
   ,ISNULL(tblQuote.ShipAddr, '') AS ShipAddr,
   tblPurchaseCodes.PurCode,
   tblPurchaseCodes.PurCodeDescription,
   tblPurchase.PurPaid,
   ISNULL(tblQuote.ShipAddr2, '') AS ShipAddr2,
   ISNULL(tblQuote.ShipCity, '') AS ShipCity,
   ISNULL(tblQuote.ShipState, '') AS ShipState,
   ISNULL(tblQuote.ShipZip, '') AS ShipZip,
   ISNULL(tblCustAddress.AddrStreet, '') AS CustStreet,
   ISNULL(tblCustAddress.AddrCity, '') AS CustCity,
   ISNULL(tblCustAddress.AddrState, '') AS CustState,
   ISNULL(tblCustAddress.AddrZip, '') AS CustZip    
   ,ISNULL((
     SELECT SUM(([QuoteSub].DiscountRate * [QuoteSub].Period) + ([QuoteSub].BillQuantity * [QuoteSub].Period))
    --[Pursub].PurAssignedCategoryId, SUM([Pursub].PurSubQty) AS SumofPurSubQty, [Pursub].PurSubCategoryDescription, [Cat].IsCategoryMisc, [QuoteSub].QuoteId, SUM([QuoteSub].BillQuantity * [QuoteSub].Period) AS BillQuantity,
    --[QuoteSub].CategoryID, [QuoteSub].DiscountRate, ([QuoteSub].DiscountRate * [QuoteSub].Period) AS RatePeriod, [QuoteSub].QuoteSubParentId, [QuoteSub].Quantity, [QuoteSub].QuoteDescription
     FROM   [dbo].[tblPurchaseSub] [Pursub] WITH (NOLOCK) 
     INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[tblCat] [Cat] WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON [Pursub].PurAssignedCategoryId = [Cat].CatId  AND 
        ([PurSub].PurAssignedCategoryId > 0) AND 
        [Cat].CDescription <> 'LABOR PROJECT MANAGER' 
   INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[tblQuoteSub] [QuoteSub] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [QuoteSub].CategoryID = [Cat].CatId
     WHERE ([PurSub].PurchaseID = tblPurchaseSub.PurchaseID) AND ([QuoteSub].QuoteId = tblQuote.QuoteID)  
   ), 0) AS [CalculatedQuoteInc]
FROM
   dbo.tblPurchase AS tblPurchase WITH (NOLOCK) 
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.tblPurchaseStatus AS tblPurchaseStatus WITH (NOLOCK) 
      ON tblPurchase.PurStatus = tblPurchaseStatus.PurStatusAutoID 
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.tblCustomers AS tblCustomers WITH (NOLOCK) 
      ON tblPurchase.CustID = tblCustomers.CustID 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.tblCustAddress AS tblCustAddress WITH (NOLOCK) 
      ON tblPurchase.CustID = tblCustAddress.CustID 
      AND tblCustAddress.AddrTypeID = 1 
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.tblBranch AS tblBranch WITH (NOLOCK) 
      ON tblPurchase.PurBranchId = tblBranch.BranchID 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.tblEmployee AS tblEmployee WITH (NOLOCK) 
      ON tblPurchase.PurSalesRep = tblEmployee.EmployeeID 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.tblEmployee AS tblEmployee_1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
      ON tblPurchase.PurApprovedBy = tblEmployee_1.EmployeeID 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.tblQuote AS tblQuote WITH (NOLOCK) 
      ON tblPurchase.PurQuoteId = tblQuote.QuoteID 
   LEFT JOIN
      dbo.tblPurchaseSub AS tblPurchaseSub WITH (NOLOCK) 
      ON tblPurchase.PurchaseID = tblPurchaseSub.PurchaseID 
   LEFT JOIN
      dbo.tblPurchaseCodes AS tblPurchaseCodes WITH (NOLOCK) 
      ON tblPurchaseSub.PurSubtype = tblPurchaseCodes.PurCode 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.tblPOLossOptions AS tblPOLossOptions WITH (NOLOCK) 
      ON tblPurchase.PO_Code = tblPOLossOptions.PO_ID 
WHERE [tblPurchase].[PurchaseID] = 21384 
GROUP BY
   tblCustomers.CustName,
   tblPurchase.PurchaseID,
   ISNULL(tblPurchase.PurInvoiceNo, 0),
   tblPurchase.PurShowName,
   tblPurchase.PurNotes,
   tblPurchase.PurDepartment,
   tblPurchase.PurQuoteId,
   tblQuote.DeliveryDate,
   tblBranch.BranchCode,
   tblBranch.BranchID,
   tblPurchaseStatus.PurStatusDesc,
   tblPurchase.PurEntered ,
   tblPurchase.PurEntered,
   tblEmployee.EmployeeName,
   tblQuote.SalesRep,
   tblQuote.ProjectLead,
   tblPurchase.PO_Code,
   tblPurchase.PurVendorID,
   tblCustomers.CustType,
   tblPurchase.PurDeliveryDate,
   tblPurchase.PurReturnDate,
   ISNULL(tblEmployee_1.EmployeeName, ''), 
   tblPurchase.PurReferenceNo,
   tblPurchase.PurTax,
   tblPurchase.PurTaxRate,
   tblPurchase.PurTaxExempt,
   tblPurchase.CustID,
   tblPurchase.PurSubTotal,
   tblPurchase.PurQuoteIncome,
   tblPurchase.PurQuoteLaborIncome,
   tblPurchase.PurLabor,
   tblPurchase.PurPoLoss,  
   tblPurchase.PurEquipment,
   tblPurchaseSub.PurSubTaxable,
   ISNULL(tblQuote.ShipAddr, '') ,
   tblPurchaseCodes.PurCode,
   tblPurchaseCodes.PurCodeDescription,
   tblPurchase.PurPaid,
   ISNULL(tblQuote.ShipAddr2, '') ,
   ISNULL(tblQuote.ShipCity, '') ,
   ISNULL(tblQuote.ShipState, ''), 
   ISNULL(tblQuote.ShipZip, ''),
   ISNULL(tblCustAddress.AddrStreet, ''), 
   ISNULL(tblCustAddress.AddrCity, ''), 
   ISNULL(tblCustAddress.AddrState, ''),
   ISNULL(tblCustAddress.AddrZip, '')
   ,tblQuote.QuoteID,
   tblPurchaseSub.PurchaseID,
   tblQuote.QuoteTotal - tblQuote.QuoteTaxAmount ,
    tblQuote.QuoteRentalID
```

[image: Ouput]

Just a simple word first row this column can be transferred in the second row?

- [EquipmentRental]
- [Labor]
- [Shipping]
- [EquipmentPurchase]
- [Others]

> Current result

```
CustName                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        PurchaseID  InvoiceNo                                          PurShowName                                                                                                                                            PurNotes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         PurDepartment                                      PurQuoteId  DeliveryDate            BranchCode                                         BranchID    PurStatusDesc                  IssuedDate              PurEntered              IssuedBy                                           SalesRep    ProjectLead PO_Code     PurVendorID CustType                                           PurDeliveryDate         PurReturnDate           ApprovedBy                                         PurReferenceNo                                     PurTax                PurTaxRate            PurTaxExempt CustID      PurSubTotal           PurQuoteIncome        PurQuoteLaborIncome   PurLabor              PurPoLoss QID        PurEquipment          Total                 QuoteRentalID EquipmentRental                         Labor                                   Shipping                                EquipmentPurchase                       Others                                  SumOfPurSubDiscTotal  PurSubTaxable TaxTotal              ShipAddr                                                                                             PurCode PurCodeDescription                                 PurPaid ShipAddr2                                          ShipCity                                           ShipState                                          ShipZip                                            CustStreet                                                                                                                                             CustCity                                           CustState                                CustZip                                            CalculatedQuoteInc     Sequance
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ------------------------------ ----------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------- --------------------- ------------ ----------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------- ---------- --------------------- --------------------- ------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------- ------------- --------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------- -------------------------------------------------- ------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------------------- --------------------
ARNOLD ASSOC                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1           0                                                  Show2005                                                                                                                                               test                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             --Select One--                                     3000        2004-03-01 06:30:00.000 LAX                                                1           CLOSED                         2005-02-17 16:08:24.000 2005-02-17 16:08:24.000 NULL                                               16          NULL        NULL        0           Vendor                                             2005-02-17 00:00:00.000 2005-02-24 00:00:00.000                                                    TEST                                               0.00                  8.25                  0            529566581   75.00                 0.00                  0.00                  75.00                 NULL      01/01/1900 0.00                  725.00                5230          0.00                                    75.00                                   0.00                                    0.00                                    0.00                                    75.00                 0             6.1875                Holiday Inn, 999 S Main St.                                                                          L       Labor                                              NULL                                                       SALT LAKE CITY                                     UT                                                 84111                                              1737 COMPROMOISE LINE                                                                                                                                  GLENDORA                                           CA                                       91741                                              0                      1
AUTOMATED BUSINESS PRODUCTS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     3           0                                                  Sundance Channel                                                                                                                                       payment on 02/28/2005- cc amex 72005. hp.                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Operations                                         7522        2005-01-17 00:00:00.000 SLC                                                57          CLOSED                         2005-02-22 10:41:30.000 2005-02-22 10:41:30.000 Jared Hunt                                         85          NULL        NULL        0           AV Company                                         2005-01-17 00:00:00.000 2005-01-31 00:00:00.000 Lalit Shah                                         7475                                               0.00                  6.85                  1            -2011940121 615.26                0.00                  0.00                  0.00                  0         01/01/1900 600.00                3552.00               11306         0.00                                    0.00                                    0.00                                    0.00                                    15.26                                   15.26                 0             1.0453                Claimjumper 573 Main Street                                                                          O       Other                                              1                                                          PARK CITY                                          UT                                                 84068                                              385 WEST 2880 SOUTH                                                                                                                                    SLC                                                UT                                       84115                                              0                      1
AUTOMATED BUSINESS PRODUCTS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     3           0                                                  Sundance Channel                                                                                                                                       payment on 02/28/2005- cc amex 72005. hp.                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Operations                                         7522        2005-01-17 00:00:00.000 SLC                                                57          CLOSED                         2005-02-22 10:41:30.000 2005-02-22 10:41:30.000 Jared Hunt                                         85          NULL        NULL        0           AV Company                                         2005-01-17 00:00:00.000 2005-01-31 00:00:00.000 Lalit Shah                                         7475                                               0.00                  6.85                  1            -2011940121 615.26                0.00                  0.00                  0.00                  0         01/01/1900 600.00                3552.00               11306         600.00                                  0.00                                    0.00                                    0.00                                    0.00                                    600.00                0             41.10                 Claimjumper 573 Main Street                                                                          R       Equipment Rental                                   1                                                          PARK CITY                                          UT                                                 84068                                              385 WEST 2880 SOUTH                                                                                                                                    SLC                                                UT                                       84115                                              0                      2
BEAT VIDEO PRODUCTIONS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1003        0                                                  SHORECLIFF COMMUNICATIONS                                                                                                                              payment on 04/06/05- chk# 3445. hp                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Operations                                         7569        2005-02-28 00:00:00.000 LAX                                                1           CLOSED                         2005-03-18 09:45:50.000 2005-03-18 09:45:50.000 Mark Davis                                         89          NULL        NULL        0           Vendor                                             2005-02-27 00:00:00.000 2005-03-04 00:00:00.000 Heena Patel                                                                                           0.00                  7.25                  1            1727531188  5119.50               0.00                  0.00                  4657.50               0         01/01/1900 0.00                  42470.00              12315         0.00                                    4657.50                                 0.00                                    0.00                                    0.00                                    4657.50               0             337.6687              Gaylord Texan (817) 778-1000                                                                         L       Labor                                              1       1501 Gaylord Trail                                 GRAPEVINE                                          TX                                                 76051                                              35 RIVERWALK WAY, UNIT 221                                                                                                                             LOWELL                                             MA                                       01854                                              0                      1
BEAT VIDEO PRODUCTIONS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1003        0                                                  SHORECLIFF COMMUNICATIONS                                                                                                                              payment on 04/06/05- chk# 3445. hp                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Operations                                         7569        2005-02-28 00:00:00.000 LAX                                                1           CLOSED                         2005-03-18 09:45:50.000 2005-03-18 09:45:50.000 Mark Davis                                         89          NULL        NULL        0           Vendor                                             2005-02-27 00:00:00.000 2005-03-04 00:00:00.000 Heena Patel                                                                                           0.00                  7.25                  1            1727531188  5119.50               0.00                  0.00                  4657.50               0         01/01/1900 0.00                  42470.00              12315         0.00                                    0.00                                    0.00                                    0.00                                    462.00                                  462.00                0             33.495                Gaylord Texan (817) 778-1000                                                                         O       Other                                              1       1501 Gaylord Trail                                 GRAPEVINE                                          TX                                                 76051                                              35 RIVERWALK WAY, UNIT 221                                                                                                                             LOWELL                                             MA                                       01854                                              0                      2
```

[image]

> Expected result
> Just want to merge repeated rows in a single row and pass some columns value in merge rows.

In the above image, you can see `PurchaseID` `1,3,3,1003,1003` repeated some row
so if `PurchaseID` returns one to more rows then need to merge some specific columns values in single rows `PurchaseID` wise.

Columns names `EquipmentRental,Labor,Shipping,EquipmentPurchase,Others`

Comment: What do you mean by *transfer* a row? This term has no clear meaning in SQL. Please show us the result that you expect.

Comment: I want to pass if `PurchaseID` repeat more then once then specific column value assing in the last row `PurchaseID`. is there any possibility?

Comment: As mention image, I want to assign `others` columns value in the last rows because both row same `PurchaseID`

Comment: Question is why they are in two different row ?

Comment: Perhaps a smaller data sample and desired results.

Comment: No @Sujitmohanty30

Comment: @JohnCappelletti adding some small data give me 1 min.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti added some extra information can you please check?

Comment: Couple things: [1] [Check if you really need the `with (nolock)`](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). [2] What makes "the first row" the first one? There is no `order by` in your query, nor a line number kind of field. [3] Aim for a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Try to demonstrate your issue with a small query (preferably less than 156 lines). [4] You still have not added the _actual expected result_, you _only described it_. Type out the results you want but cannot generate with the query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)